# What is the time and space complexity of this code? I'm very confused on this subject so I am asking

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is my code, it is a russian peasant multiplication algorithm. I find the time and space complexity very confusing so I needed some help.

This is also for java language

Thank you.

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());


int res=0;

 // While second number doesn't become 1

    while (num2 > 0)

    {

         // If second number becomes odd, 

         // add the first number to result

         if ((num2 & 1) != 0)

             res = res + num1;



        // Double the first number 

        // and halve the second number

        num1 = num1 << 1;

        num2 = num2 >> 1;

    }

   jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(res));
}
```

Comment: Tim Biegelesien is correct: the "time complexity" of your algorithm is O(log 2).  The reason is that each iteration essentially cuts the remaining amount of data in to be processed in half.  A binary search, for example, is also O(log 2).  Here's a good article: https://medium.com/@acodercalledcole/big-o-notation-breakdown-c7e12dc3778.  Please "upvote" and "accept" his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop continues to execute provided that `num2` be greater than zero.  After each iteration of the loop, `num2` is halved.  This means that the loop will execute `log_2(num2)` times.  So, assuming `num2` be represented by `N`, we can say that the complexity of this loop is `log_2(N)`.